# HighCharts Axes Alignment

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a simple chart with a Y and X axis, by default the X axis is displayed at the bottom of the chart, how can I position that and move it to the top of the chart?

I have looked into the API reference and the closest option I found was the "opposite" option but that will put 2 axes on the chart while I only want to have one which is positioned at the top of the chart.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the ***opposite*** option is what you need to use to move the xAxis to the top of the chart.  Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VNbLq/1/) of it working as you are needing it to.  As you can see there is no xAxis labels at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: Brilliant! I must have overlooked :-) Thanks alot.